# How to print format variable without newline in Cython

Tags: python-3.x, cython

```
$ cython --version
Cython version 0.25.2
$ python --version
Python 3.5.1

$ python setup.py build_ext -i

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name, end='')
                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

hello.pyx:2:33: Expected ')', found '='

$ cat hello.pyx
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name, end='')
    print("Hello ", end='')

$ cat setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'hello',
  ext_modules = cythonize("hello.pyx")
)
```

Question> How to print in Cython without newline?

Thank you

Comment: I haven't tested it myself but that looks like a bug. It might be worth reporting at https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: Additionally, it looks like using `end=` is in the Cython test cases: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/a0bbb940c847dfe92cac446c8784c34c28c92836/tests/run/print_function.pyx. The only difference is that they seem to be using a space rather than an empty string

Comment: @DavidW, thank you for your suggestion. The fix is to include the line `from __future__ import print_function`. No other changes are required.

Comment: You use py3 print function, you have to tell cython it's py3 (cython default is py2 syntax ). So `ext_modules = cythonize(["hello.pyx"], language_level=3)`. Of course, you can also use `__future__` for compatibility of py2 and py3.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have Cython at hand to test, but printing directly to stdout ought to do the trick:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello %s!" % name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't want print a newline?

In py2:

```
print item,  # the comma ',' does the trick.
```

In py3:

```
print(item, end='')
```

Cython compiling is default to py2 syntax. If one use syntax only valid in py3, then when compiling, `language_level=3` in setup, or `cython -3` in command line, or `%%cython -3` in jupyter notebook must be explicitly given.

One more thing, one can write py2 syntax in cython, but link to py3 header and library, it is an easy way to port py2 to py3.